# Regex For Multiple Lines in Knime

Tags: java, regex, line-breaks, knime

I am using Knime to find a pattern like AB1234 anywhere in the data of one of my columns X. X can have multiple lines in each cell but I can't figure out how to search all of the lines. Below is my current regex, can you please help me search all lines

I tried this first to search but it only matched if that pattern appeared in the first line of the cell, did not work for cells with line breaks:

```
.*?[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{4}.*
```

Then I tried to do this to search all of my lines but it didn't work and only searched the first line again:

```
(.*|[\r\n])[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{4}(.*|[\r\n])
```

Comment: Do a global search `/.*?[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{4}.*/g`

Comment: Now there aren't any matches with that

Comment: Can you give us an example string? /g is for global search. Meaning it'll match all occurrences. You'll usually also see i which means ignore case. The "g" flag indicates that the regular expression should be tested against all possible matches in a string

Comment: It would be something like text, linebreak, textAB1234text. I am getting stuck on matching with a linebreak

Comment: Not sure which regex are you using. See this example: https://regex101.com/r/eb5C5q/1 and try running your regex here.

Comment: I am using the regex from the node "String Manipulation" in Knime. My data originally comes from ServiceNow and then I load it into Knime via an excel file. Certain cells in my excel files have multiple lines and I cannot match if my pattern exists outside of the first line. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the inline [embedded flag expression for multiline mode](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#MULTILINE), `(?m)` and the [embedded DOTALL flags](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#DOTALL), `(?s)` together:

Your first expression would look like this:

```
(?ms).*?([A-Z]{2}[0-9]{4}).*
```

[image: Screenshot of the workflow]

Comment: this still does not work - how does the (?m) work in Knime? Should I be specifying that expression with the rest of the regex code in the string manipulation node?

Comment: Hi @RachelKatz added `DOTALL` (`(?s)`) too. I did not know you wanted to remove the whole content around it.